# Holomorphic $f$ on Unit disk s.t. $|f^{(n)}(0)| \geq (n!)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine whether there exists a holomorphic function $f: U_1(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $|f^{(n)}(0)| \geq (n!)^2$.

If $f$ was holomorphic then $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ for all $z \in U_1(0)$ where $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ and $|a_n| \geq n!$. How should I proceed?

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0}{a_nz^n}$?

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of that series around zero? Use the root test.

Comment: It's $0$ since $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \geq \sqrt[n]{n!}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could proceed by noting that, if $|a_n|\geqslant n!$ for each $n$, then the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $0$.